# Is it possible to call one activity from two different activities in android

Tags: android, android-activity, data-transfer

So, I  have 2 activities, the first one(lets call this A) passes data to an activity with a list, lets call this B. B then uses the data from A and makes a list out of it.A service S is then called by B. The service then calls another activity lets say C, which in turn starts B. Should B still work with all the data?BTW all activities are ActionBarActivities.

Comment: Yes the code is wayyy to convoluted and long for me to post up here, I have literally been ripping my hair out over this.

Comment: so what have you concluded from your code ? should it work or not ? what errors/problems are you facing ? you will get a good answer if you try to be more specific.

Comment: Logcat does not help, and I am pretty sure the error occours when I use startActivity. I think it is because the data isn't getting transferred properly but I would not know, nor do I have enough credits to go to chat with this issue

Comment: that depends on the launch mode of your activity. See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode From your description, you possibly want singleTask. Alternatively, start your activity from C with the `REORDER_TO_FRONT` flag: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but how do you exactly use 'REORDER_TO_FRONT'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the general case, each time an activity in invoked using `startActivity`, a new instance is create.

This behavior can be modified by the use of the [`launchMode`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode). `singleTask` will always be the same instance, but your activity must be at the root of the task

An existing activity can also be called back to the front of the stack using the flag [FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT). It is unclear in the documentation how the new data is passed, or whether the previous data in the activity is kept.

Comment: So would this work:Intent getfinIntent = new Intent(LockScreen.this,MainActivity2.class);
getfinIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
                startActivity(getfinIntent);

Comment: that's what I would try, yes.

Comment: You deserve an award, thanks for helping me for like the second time dude.